# How to retrieve HTML from view object without rendering to the browser

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 2 separate partials views. I want to get the HTML with the given data from those partials views and have to send a `Json` response from controller.

Here is my code snippet.

```
public function myControllerFunction()
{
    $response['products'] = view('search._partials.product_box')->with('data', $data['products]);
    $response['filters'] = view('search._partials.facet_filters')->with('data', $data['filters]);
    return $response;        
}
```

I want to achieve some thing like it. This is possible with plain php code but is there any way to achieve it with this framework.

Answer (score 0):

Just use render() function to generate html from view in controller

Your function should look like this

```
public function myControllerFunction()
{
    $response['products'] = view('search._partials.product_box')->with('data', $data['products])->render();
    $response['filters'] = view('search._partials.facet_filters')->with('data', $data['filters])->render();
    return response()->json($response);        
}
```